# How to format date to a certain way in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) % 7), GETDATE())
```

Which displays:

```
2014-04-19 10:47:46.790
```

How can I modify the query so it displays `04/19/2014` or `04-19-2014`

Comment: Are you _really_ just displaying it or are you passing it to some other system?

Comment: I will be passing it to an SSRS report as DATE which I am thinking I can do it like this: `CAST( THE DATE, AS DATE)` before passing it.

Comment: A google search on mssql convert will lead you to the information on how to format dates and times.

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: @SiKni8 then let the _report_ format the date - don't do it in the query.

Comment: @DStanley I think that's what I will do. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, 0 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) % 7), GETDATE()), 101)`

**Outputs**

`04/19/2014`

And

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, 0 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) % 7), GETDATE()), 110)`

**Outputs**

`04-19-2014`

Alternately, you could format this in the consuming application (in your case, SSRS).  This could be done like this

```
=Format(date_column, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

or

```
=Format(date_column, "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: I think the second option will be great. Thanks. UPVOTED and ACCEPTED.

Comment: Should I use a CAST() to pass it as date and not as a string?

Comment: You will have to pass it as a string to get it formatted the way you want it.  The `DATE` or `DATETIME` type in SQL will always be formatted the way that you mentioned in the original post.  With that, I notice you said you're going to use this in SSRS.  Perhaps the formatting should be done *in* SSRS, using some tools that it has available

Comment: @SiKni8, see the latest update, I've included how you'd do it in SSRS

Comment: Thanks! I will take your answer and play around in SSRS.

Comment: Question is, if I run the same query on, lets say 4/28/2014. Will it give me the 4/26/2014 date? I want the query to always display the last Saturday's date.

Comment: @Tom personal preference, but I find it's cleaner to use the `Format` property of a control versus setting the value of a control to an expression.

Answer (score 4):

for 04/22/2014

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)
```

for 04-22-2014

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 110)
```

Answer (score 3):

Date formatting is *generally* the responsibility of the presentation layer, not the data layer.  `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format - it's literally a representation of a date and time of day.  When you *display* the `DateTime` is when you choose the format (if you don't choose one, the system will choose one by default).

You *could* convert the `DateTime` to a `varchar`, but if the value is getting consumed by some other system then I would *strongly* recommend leaving it as a `DateTime` and letting the part of the system that *displays* the date convert it appropriately.  Otherwise, if you need to do any kind of date math/comparison/etc., the system is going to have to convert *back* to a date value which could cause problems.

Based on your subsequent comment I would format the date in the SSRS report appropriately and let the query produce the data value as-is.

Answer (score 2):

I use this to show date only portion:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(DAY, 0 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) % 7), GETDATE()), 110)
```

Will that work for you?

Comment: I can use it except I will be running the SQL server agent on Sunday hence the query which will get the date from the day before (Saturday's date)

Comment: Also look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp for additional formats - in case this does not work for you.